# excute shell by php on xampp error

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I want to back up a table on localhost using code.

```
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'snapmall';
$dbtable = 'tb_translation';
$dbpath = 'D:test/new/';

//mysqldump -u root -p snapmall ps_translation > D:/test/new/ps_translation.sql
$command = "mysqldump -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname $dbtable > ".$dbpath.$dbtable.".sql";

shell_exec($command);
```

I have test command on shell of xampp and it working fine, but when I run it by command shell_exec() have a result the file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add the 2>&1 to get the output from your command:

```
$output = shell_exec($command." 2>&1");
```

Then post it here.

You need to be able to execute your command by calling xamp before, because your exec is accessing the bash, not the xampp, so, on other words, the set of basic commands must be accessible to your exec, configure your PATH variable.

Comment: Result is emty but I have try: exec('ls -l 2>&1', $output); print_r($output); and recived message: Array ( [0] => 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )

Comment: So, your PHP exec is not working on shell, you need to change your PATH variable and be able to execute any command, when you do this, it will work ;)

Comment: I run command: mysqldump -u root -p leo_snapmall ps_translation > D:/www/prestashop/ps_translation.sql by cmd it work find but my code not work:      exec('mysqldump -u root -p leo_snapmall ps_translation > D:/www/prestashop/ps_translation.sql 2>&1'); => error message: 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Your exec does not know any of your commands, you need to specify it on your PHP configuration.

Comment: You need to be able to execute your command by calling xamp before, because your exec is accessing the bash, not the xampp

Comment: I will try do it. Thank you so much